# Multiple POST params in node.js POST, using needle

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, express, needle.js

I am trying to POST some data to this API end point , Corresponding curl call is this :

```
curl -X POST \
    -d "apiKey=YOU_API_KEY" \
    -d "extractors=entities,entailments" \
    -d "text=Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell off its vast portfolio of industrial holdings that includes a stake in the parent company of British Airways and Iberia." \
    https://api.textrazor.com/
```

If i directly try to use this with needle specifying API KEY , it connects to the API successfully but since it is missing the `text` param it gives me an error. So how do I specify the multiple `POST` params.

My code :

```
needle.post(TEXTRAZOR_URL,TEXTRAZOR_API_KEY,function(err, razorResponse){

      console.log(err || razorResponse.body);
  });
```

here `TEXTRAZOR_URL` is : `https://api.textrazor.com/`
and `TEXTRAZOR_API_KEY`  is : `apiKey=123123123`

I know that i need to change the 2nd parameter in needle.post. How do I do this.

Answer (score 0):

try using chrome extension POSTMAN

Comment: not exactly what I am looking for I want to do this in node.js